# How to check form submission ASP classic

Tags: forms, post, asp-classic

I'm setting up a form in ASP classic and it will reload after submission (action self)

But this time it shows results of previous submissions, so how can I check that a POST submission has been made?

Like in PHP:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
  show results...
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have several options:

**Method 1** - Check the request method:

```
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    'Show Results...
End If
```

**Method 2** - add a hidden field to your form with a value then check if that value has been posted:

```
If Request.form("HiddenValue") = "1" Then
    'Show Results...
End If
```

**Method 3** - Check if the request.form collection contains items:

```
If Request.Form.Count > 0 Then
    'Show Results...
End If
```

**Method 4** - Post to a querystring (i.e. set `action` of `<form>` to `?post=yes`)

```
If Request.QueryString("post") = "yes" Then
    'Show Results...
End If
```

**Which one to pick?**

My preferred option is method 4 – as it’s easily visible in the address bar as to what’s going on – if for some reason I want to avoid presenting this level of detail in the url, I tend to use option 3 as it’s easy to implement, requires no changes on the source forms & is reliable.
As for the other two methods:

- **Method 1** – I tend to avoid relying on server variables if I don’t
  have 100% control over the server – no real justification for that,
  just a general habit I tend to work with.
- **Method 2** – You could substitute a hidden field for another field that will always contain
  a value.

Comment: Thats nice, but which would you recommend?  How do the different approaches compare?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Aye, good point, answer edited to give a bit of clarification.

Comment: FWIW, I would recommend Method 1.  Weird FUD over a server you don't control is irrational, if you can't trust the server to  do something basic like this then perhaps you should find a different host.   The `REQUEST_METHOD` variable is there for the express purpose of detecting which HTTP Method is being used.  Methods 2 and 4 require the developer to pollute their code with unnecessary content so IMO should be avoided when alternatives are available.  Method 4 is also a pretty good approach but lacks the clarity of purpose that Method 1 does.

Comment: I think even IIS can get the `REQUEST_METHOD` variable right.